# Função em Javascript para marcar checkbox dependendo de condição

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Preciso fazer uma função if else em Javascript que ***se a coluna "valor_conjunto" for igual a '0,00', então o checkbox é marcado, se não, o checkbox permanece desmarcado***. Essa função precisa ser executada ao carregar a página automaticamente.

**O que já tentei?**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var valor_conjunto = '0,00';
    
    if (valor_conjunto == '0,00') {
      $('#checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = true;               
      });
      
    } else {
        $('#checkbox').each(function() {
        this.checked = false;               
      });
    }
    
}
```

Já tentei vários códigos, mas o mais próximo foi esse, sou iniciante com Javascript, então não tenho certeza se estou errando em alguma parte do código. Link do Fiddle com o código da pergunta: http://jsfiddle.net/fqnwphx5/3/

Answer (score 2):

No seu exemplo está usando jQuery com um seletor por ID (`$('#checkbox')`), nesse caso não precisa usar um `each`, pois vai retornar um elemento só.

Além disso, use `prop('checked', true);` para setar checked em um input:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var valor_conjunto = '0,00';
    
    if (valor_conjunto == '0,00') {
      $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);               
    } else {
        $('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);           
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Checkbox 1
```